# How to display the values for plotted x values in a bar graph using matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, bar-chart, visualization

I want to show the exact value of the that has been plotted in the x-axis.
[image: what I got]

In this figure the value plotted in the x axis is 248.

I want to display the value 248 near the bar that has been plotted near the x-axis.

something like this
[image: expected]

This is the code used to generate the graph

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
pos = np.arange(len(count_dict.keys()))
my_colors = 'rgbkymc'
plt.figure(figsize=(80, 30))  # width:80, height:30
plt.bar(range(len(count_dict)), count_dict.values(), align='edge', width=0.5,color=my_colors)
plt.title("MinMaxScalerGaussianNB",fontsize=60)
 
# Setting the x and y labels
plt.xlabel("Number of Iterations",fontsize=45)
plt.ylabel("Number of appearances in each iteration",fontsize=45)
  
# Setting the number of ticks
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, len(count_dict)+1, 50),fontsize=34)
plt.yticks( fontsize=34)
plt.xlim(xmin=0) 
plt.show()
```

Comment: you can add plt.text(x, y, s) (s being the text you want to add)

Comment: You can see this article https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-label-the-values-plots-with-matplotlib-c9b7db0fd2e1 . It's really like @CharlieBONS said, you can generalize it putting everything inside a for loop.